# Grab MySQL error in Django and JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, django, exception

I wonder, how can I grab MySQL error in Django and then send it to JS so that I can alert the corresponding message to JS so that the user understands what went wrong during the transaction.

MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `some_sp`(IN param VARCHAR(300))
new_legal_entity:BEGIN

CASE 
    WHEN -- some condition 
    BEGIN
        SIGNAL specialty
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '**MY CUSTOMIZED ERROR MESSAGE**'
        LEAVE new_legal_entity;
  -- ....
```

Python (Django):

```
def create_new_vendor(request, param):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    sqlCmd = ("call some_sp(" + "'" + param  + ")")
    cursor.execute(sqlCmd)
    cursor.close()
    return render_to_response('vendors.html',{})
```

JS:

```
var createNewVendor = function() {

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",

        data:{},
        url:"/some_sp" +
        "/param/" + $('#param').val(),

        success:
            function(response)
        {
            $('#1С_id').val('');
            alert("DB SP Success");
            buildVendorsTable ();
        }
    });

    return true;
};
```

So the question is, how can I display "MY CUSTOMIZED ERROR MESSSAGE" to the user ?

Comment: I don't think this should be easy in this way. maybe you should reconsider your method. For example, why low-level call an sql procedure which is easy to port in simple python with django orm? Then it should be easy to use django messaging framework.

Comment: hm ... you can return it and fetch https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone etc